# Get Data from 3 Tables Based on Child Table Releationship by using Laravel Eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I'm new on this site and also new to Laravel. 
I have 3 tables.

1) Product Table (column: id, product_name)

2) Purchase Table (Column: id, purchase_date)

3) Purchase Items (Colunn: id, purchase_id, product_id);

**Releationships**

I have oneToMany Relationship Between **Purchase** & **PurchaseItem** Model, and oneToMany relationship between **Product** & **PurchaseItem**.

**My Problem**

In my Purchase Model I'm getting purchaseItems Data easily as I have relationship between them. But I want to get Product Data also (Like: product_name) in Purchase Model. How can I get it? any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can just call the relation of your PurchaseItem as you did for Purchase :

```
 $purchases = Purchase::all();

 foreach ($purchases as $purchase) {
      // get all items
      $purchaseItems = $purchase->purchaseItems;

      foreach ($purchaseItems as $purchaseItem) {
           // you can $purchaseItem->product
           echo $purchaseItem->product->product_name;
      }
 }
```

Comment: Thank you boss. It worked. But the Probelm is when I'm using it into blade file quires are increasing. I want to apply Eager Loading Process.